# Properties of limit; a conceptual problem.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

It's taught that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}g(h)f(h) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} g(h) \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(h)$.

If I consider $f(h) = 1/h^2$ and $g(h)=h$
then their product is$ 1/h$, and as $h$ tends to zero it blows up to infinity. But if I use the result I get limit of $g=0$ as $h$ tends to zero and thus product becomes zero.
What is wrong with my thought process? Please help if the result is not applied as expected.

Comment: Please use \to instead of -> .

Comment: Look up the conditions of that first theorem you cited. You should find that it is only guaranteed to be true when both limits are finite.

Comment: Why should we even care about the second one if we know that limit of first one turns out to be zero?

Comment: For exactly the reason you point out in your question: if it is not the case that both limits exist, then you cannot apply the theorem.

Comment: Is there any other theorem to use if we are unable to know the limits beforehand.; or as in this case if one becomes infinite while other is zero

Comment: The theorem is that if $ \lim_{h\to 0}f(h)=F\in \Bbb R$ and if $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=G\in \Bbb R$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)g(h)=FG.$.. BUT if $f(h)=1/h$ when $h\ne 0$ then for every $F\in \Bbb R$ the sentence $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)=F$ is a false sentence. So if $f(h)=1/h$ when $h \ne 0$ then  the theorem does not say anything about the limit of $f(h)g(h)$.

Comment: We should especially care if the limit of one of the factors is zero. On the other hand if $f(h) \to L\neq 0$ as $h\to 0$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)g(h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)$ no matter what happens with $g$.